# What is the difference between magnetic and primary inductance?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductance, flyback

I try to calculate **ramp compensation resistor (Rcomp)** for **flyback SMPS** converter design. For this, I examined *slope compensation* section at **page 15** in **[NCP1252 datasheet by OnSemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1252-D.PDF)**.

But, there is a parameter which I don't understand. Calculations are below as screenshot:

[image]

**Mixed point !!!**
Ns/Np = 0,085
Lout = 27µH
Lmag = 13mH (?) **WHY?**

As I know, L2 = L1 x (N2/N1)^2
So, Lout = Lmag x (0,085)^2 = 27µH   --> Lmag must be 3,7mH
But, Lmag = 13mH *in NCP1252 datasheet*

**Are magnetic and primary inductance different each other?**

Comment: No, they are not different unless you want to take into account leakage inductance (2 to 5%).

Comment: This calculation in NCP1252 is wrong?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: wouldn't Lin=L1=0.085²*13mH=94uH ? or x2 for both primary legs?

Comment: This question can be asked in both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Are magnetic and primary inductance different each other?*

No, they are not different unless you want to take into account leakage inductance (2 to 5%). I think you are not understanding the type of circuit they refer to: -

[image]

Page 16 and 17 are referring to a `2 switch−Forward Power supply specification` and they use an extra inductor in the output circuit seen as L1 in the above schematic. That will be the 27 uH they refer to: -

[image]

Comment: How can I calculate this values according to flyback topology? If Lout = 27uH, Lp = 3,7mH. Is it true?

Comment: It's not a flyback circuit. It's a forward converter topology.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there is no clear app note for flyback as I search. I can not calculate this resistor. Especially, NCP1252 app note is very shallow for this matter. Can you guide me about this? Which app note or article do I have to read?

Comment: I can't guide you on this. This is a question and answer site and I don't know what resistor value you refer to. Lengthy discussions about this or that are frowned upon. Why do you refer to a resistor BTW?